# Samsung smart TV IME loading issue

Tags: javascript, samsung-smart-tv

I have a ime.js and a html which loads the js to invoke IME. However, the html can not be shown all the time when I run the project and maybe it is just too slow and there is no error message in the console as well. But when I comment `<script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript/ime.js"></script>` in the html, the html can be shown immediately. What might be the problem? Did I miss some configuration?

Any help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please try include script in the end of the body tags:

```
...
    <script type='text/javascript' src='$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/IME_XT9/ime.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/IME_XT9/inputCommon/ime_input.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

It's because IME starts work with DOM immediately

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I have these two lines in the start of the body, and I tried to move them to the end, it was still not working